# Why doesn't SQL Server's xml.modify with a JOIN update all the elements specified?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I've googled and read a bunch of this, but I still don't understand why this code doesn't work. I know .modify() is a "singleton", but it doesn't explain to me why it's not executing once per row in the returned set. This makes zero sense to me, and I'm just hoping to come to some understanding. Honestly, this feels like a bug, not expected behavior.

Basically, I'm trying to update xml based on a table of inputs that I cannot predict ahead of time (it will be different for every client). I want to update by just joining to a table that describes the updates, and having it work. But it doesn't.

I've boiled it down to this example. In this example, I expect the code to update each node specified with the vegetable="false" attribute. Note that I use the "sql:Column()" syntax to navigate to the correct node to update. But it only updates the first one:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @xml xml = '<top>
    <element name="apple">red</element>
    <element name="pear">green</element>
    <element name="banana">yellow</element>
</top>';

DECLARE @xmlData TABLE (ID int, Contents xml);
DECLARE @elements TABLE (ID int, Element varchar(50));

INSERT INTO @xmlData (ID, Contents) VALUES (1, @xml);
INSERT INTO @elements(ID, Element)
VALUES (1, 'apple'), (2, 'pear'), (3, 'banana');

SET NOCOUNT OFF;
SELECT *
  FROM @xmlData CROSS JOIN @elements;

UPDATE x
   SET Contents.modify('insert attribute vegetable {"false"} into (/top/element[@name=sql:column("y.Element")])[1]')
  FROM @xmlData x
       CROSS JOIN @elements y

SELECT * FROM @xmlData;
```

I put the select in to show that it returns three rows, so I expect three updates. But the SET NOCOUNT OFF shows that only one row is updated. THIS MAKES NO SENSE.

The only way around this I've found it to put a WHILE loop in, but that seems ridiculous because the intent is already perfectly and explicitly stated in the code above... it just doesn't work.

This code works, but I have no clue why I have to go through this kind of hack and performance killer just to do something painfully obvious:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @xml xml = '<top>
    <element name="apple">red</element>
    <element name="pear">green</element>
    <element name="banana">yellow</element>
</top>';

DECLARE @xmlData TABLE (ID int, Contents xml);
DECLARE @elements TABLE (ID int, Element varchar(50));

INSERT INTO @xmlData (ID, Contents) VALUES (1, @xml);
INSERT INTO @elements(ID, Element)
VALUES (1, 'apple'), (2, 'pear'), (3, 'banana');

SET NOCOUNT OFF;
SELECT *
  FROM @xmlData CROSS JOIN @elements;

DECLARE @maxElement int = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @elements);
DECLARE @currentElement int = 1;

WHILE (@currentElement <= @maxElement)
BEGIN
    UPDATE x
       SET Contents.modify('insert attribute vegetable {"false"} into (/top/element[@name=sql:column("y.Element")])[1]')
      FROM @xmlData x
           CROSS JOIN @elements y
     WHERE y.ID = @currentElement
     SET @currentElement += 1;
END

SELECT * FROM @xmlData;
```

Can someone explain to me why the modify isn't executed once per row in the first block? And is the solution I have in the second block the best solution here? It really feels like a gross hack to me... but I do not know the element names or the count of element names ahead of time, so I can't just do what most articles recommend which is just writing multiple UPDATE statements. UPDATE with a JOIN should do the right thing, I thought. And I'm stumped about why it doesn't.

Comment: I should point out that when there are multiple rows in the @xmlData, ALL of the rows get updated... but only the first node in each gets updated. So the modify() is executing multiple times with the join, but only ONCE per specific xml content, even though there are multiple rows per xml content, so it should be executing multiple times within the same statement.

Comment: An XML file is a single row in the database.  The first method you are not enumerating through the elements of the xml file.  The second method works because you are enumerating through the elements of the xml file.

Comment: That still doesn't make sense to me. Because the xml is repeated on every row, so the update should execute the modify() on each row, and on each row, the xml is the 'same' so it should be updating it multiple times. that's what the join is doing... producing multiple rows, one for each 'element' to be updated. This is how non-xml updates work....

Comment: Why do you say "the xml is repeated on every row"?  What methods did you use to determine that the data was on separate rows?  Could you just be seeing one row of the database with a carriage return after each element.

Comment: That's precisely what the SELECT shows. That's why I included that select, so show that there are THREE rows. The update does the join so you get all three element names. But it ignores all but the first one. Which makes no sense. Run the SQL above to see.

Comment: When you cross join three items you get two pairs. 1 : 2 and 1 : 3.

Comment: @jdweng, when you cross join one row with three rows, you get three rows: 1:1, 1:2, and 1:3. As shown in my example code. My question is why the result of the modify only seems to operate on the first one. Why doesn't the modify execute on the other two as well? The same row should be updated three times.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to do it by using *XQuery FLWOR* expression. It does it through XML reconstruction. Also, I added some protection if the `@vegetable` attribute already exists. *XQuery* `contains()` function checks if the element is on the update list. I added a new **fig** element to test it.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @xmlData TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Contents XML);
INSERT INTO @xmlData (Contents) 
VALUES ('<top>
    <element name="apple" vegetable="true">red</element>
    <element name="pear">green</element>
    <element name="fig">reddish</element>
    <element name="banana">yellow</element>
</top>');

DECLARE @elements TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Element VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @elements(Element)
VALUES ('apple'), ('pear'), ('banana');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- before
SELECT * FROM @xmlData;

DECLARE @element_list AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @element_list += ',[' + el.Element + ']'
FROM @elements AS el;

-- just to see
SELECT @element_list AS [element_list];

DECLARE @vegetable VARCHAR(10) = 'false';

UPDATE @xmlData
SET Contents = Contents.query('<top>
    {
        for $x in /top/element
        return if(empty($x/@vegetable)
                    and contains(sql:variable("@element_list"), concat("[",$x/@name,"]"))) then (
            <element name="{($x/@name)}">{data($x)}
                {attribute vegetable {sql:variable("@vegetable")}}
            </element>)
            else ($x)
    }
</top>');

-- after
SELECT * FROM @xmlData;
```

Unfortunately, even the latest SQL Server 2019 still doesn't support XQuery 3.0 or 3.1 based on the w3c standards.

### Useful links:

(1) [XQuery Update](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Update)
(2) [SQL Server vNext (post 2019) and NoSQL functionality](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38142115-sql-server-vnext-post-2019-and-nosql-functionali)

Comment: Great, +1 from my side

Comment: I don't see where this is taking data from the table to determine which element names to update? I know my example updated all of them, but I explicitly stated that what gets updated is an ARGUMENT to the operation. It's different for every customer. There is a table that says what named element nodes to update. And I need to use that table to update the xml. This solution seems to hard-code everything, updating all nodes always... which doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @pmbAustin, I updated the answer based on your latest clarifications. Check it out.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky That's an interesting solution... I'm not sure which is more efficient, that or the one I have in my question above... but it doesn't really answer my question, which is "Why doesn't the code in my first block of code in the question work?" It, by all logic and reasonable expectations, SHOULD work. It should update the xml three times, once with information on each column. But it only executes once, for the first column property. And I cannot fathom any reason as to why that is.